# Angular/AG-Grid - Scrolling to the wrong position in table after unhiding a column. Using setColumnVisible & ensureColumnVisible

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am writing an AG-Grid table in Angular and I try to do the following feature:

> Scroll to the desired column (I'm using **ensureColumnVisible** function) AND if the column is hidden, unhide first and then scroll to it.

I know it's a very specific detail, but in case someone had an experience with this specific '' bug ''. I'll call it a bug...

Scrolling to already unhidden column using **ensureColumnVisible**  works just fine

```
this.gridApi.ensureColumnVisible(colId, 'start');
```

But when I try to unhide the column AND THEN scroll to its position, it unhides the column and then just scrolls to the wrong position (scrolls little bit to the left, that's all).

```
  if (!matchingColumn.suppressColumnsToolPanel && matchingColumn.hide) {
    this.gridOptions.columnApi.setColumnVisible(colId, true);
  }
  this.gridApi.ensureColumnVisible(colId, 'start');
```